# Mouse over event only working on one card

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmw97.jpg)

I'm using a mouse over event to have the shadows change from black to pink. However, when I add the mosue over event onto the other cards they only change the first card. How to I get each indivual card to change colour when hovered?

JS

```
<script>
    function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementById("CardHover").style.boxShadow = "-6px 6px 0px 0px #FF8A88";
    }
    
    function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementById("CardHover").style.boxShadow = "-6px 6px 0px 0px #000";
    }
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="report" id="CardHover" onclick="location.href='#';" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 10px;" src="#.png" alt="">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start; gap: 6px; padding: 8px;">
                <h6>#ServiceDesign  #DesignThinking  #Ethnography</h6>
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Body Copy</p>
                <a href="#" class="tertiary">Explore</a>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="report" id="CardHover" onclick="location.href='#';" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 10px;" src="#.png" alt="">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start; gap: 6px; padding: 8px;">
                <h6>#ServiceDesign  #DesignThinking  #Ethnography</h6>
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Body Copy</p>
                <a href="#" class="tertiary">Explore</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Expectng to have each card have it's own hover using mosue over events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code is because you're repating the same `id` attribute value on all the card elements. This is invalid as `id` *must be unique*. To fix that problem change the `id` to a `class`.

That being said, there's quite a few other problems in the code which need addressing:

- Use unobtrusive event handlers created in JS, not inline `onX` attributes in your HTML. The former allow you to get a reference to the element that raised the event from the Event object, so that you can update it as required.
- Use `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` and not `mouseover`. The latter fires once *for every pixel the mouse moves* over the target element, which is overkill in this use case.
- Put your CSS in an external stylesheet, not in the HTML.
- Don't put `click` event handlers that cause page redirects on elements which cannot accept a click event by default - eg. a `div`. This is because it's very poor for accessibility.

With all that said, here's an updated working implementation:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.CardHover');
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    e.target.style.boxShadow = '-6px 6px 0px 0px #FF8A88';
  });

  card.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    e.target.style.boxShadow = '-6px 6px 0px 0px #000';
  });
});
```

```css
.report {
  box-shadow: -6px 6px 0px 0px #000;
}

.report>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.report>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 6px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="report CardHover">
  <img src="#.png" alt="">
  <div>
    <h6>#ServiceDesign #DesignThinking #Ethnography</h6>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Body Copy</p>
    <a href="#" class="tertiary">Explore</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="report CardHover">
  <img src="#.png" alt="">
  <div>
    <h6>#ServiceDesign #DesignThinking #Ethnography</h6>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Body Copy</p>
    <a href="#" class="tertiary">Explore</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

***However***, the above is almost entirely moot because you should be using CSS to update the UI, not JS. Here's how to do that using the `:hover` pseudo-selector:

```css
.report {
  box-shadow: -6px 6px 0px 0px #000;
}

.report:hover {
  box-shadow: -6px 6px 0px 0px #FF8A88;
}

.report>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.report>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 6px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="report CardHover">
  <img src="#.png" alt="">
  <div>
    <h6>#ServiceDesign #DesignThinking #Ethnography</h6>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Body Copy</p>
    <a href="#" class="tertiary">Explore</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="report CardHover">
  <img src="#.png" alt="">
  <div>
    <h6>#ServiceDesign #DesignThinking #Ethnography</h6>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Body Copy</p>
    <a href="#" class="tertiary">Explore</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory and David. This has been super helpful